# Korea Incheon airport 22hr and 14hr Layover visa

Tags: transit, transit-visas, layovers, south-korea

I am Nepali with Nepali passport. I am on Temporary Protected Status and I have advanced parole. My flight details are SEATTLE-ICN-NEPAL (22hr) and NEPAL-ICN-SEATTLE (14hr). My question is, would I be able to get out and in the airport to tour the city?Would customs be a problem? Do I need a visa?

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing where ICN is..

Comment: Incheon airport

Comment: @Hilmar You are not familiar with Korea's transit tourist program? [Many other nationalities can exit the airport](https://www.hikorea.go.kr/pt/InfoDetailR_en.pt?categoryId=2&parentId=385&catSeq=401&showMenuId=375) on a transit tour during their layover.

Comment: If I stay in the airport for the layovers, do I still need visa? And if I do transit tour, do I still need visa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Most nationalities](https://www.hikorea.go.kr/pt/InfoDetailR_en.pt?categoryId=2&parentId=385&catSeq=401&showMenuId=375) can take advantage of [Korea's transit tourist program](https://www.airport.kr/ap_cnt/en/trn/tour/trtour/trtour.do) to exit the airport and take one of [several short tours](https://www.airport.kr/ap_cnt/en/trn/tour/trcose/trcose.do) when traveling to or from various Western countries.

> - Eligible countries
>
>   - Applicable to all countries (save forMacedonia, Cuba, Syria, Sudan and Iran, Republic of Kosovo, Palestine, Afghanistan, Iraq, Nigeria, Ghana, Yemen) that are not granted visa-free entry into Korea.
> - Applicable to…
>
>   - Persons holding a visa (re-entry permit, permanent residency, etc.) to enter the U.S. (including Guam and Saipan), Canada, Australia, or New Zealand (hereinafter referred to as "the four advanced countries")
>     1) who transit through Korea to go to one of the four advanced countries.
>     2) who stay in one of the four advanced countries and take a direct flight from the country to Korea to go to a country of origin or a third country.
>     i) A person who has an entry visa for one of 30 European countries, and wishes to travel to 30 European countries through South Korea, or departs from one of 30 European countries, and wishes to travel one’s home country or the third country through South Korea.
>     Eligibility
>     (1)A person who has a departure ticket to the countries above within 30 days from South Korea, for who has not been an illegal alien and non endorsable offences.
>     (2) In the past 3 years, a person who has not been denied entry to Korea, who has not given deportation order from Korea and a person who has not been an illegal alien and a person who has not violated laws.
>     (3) A person who stayed in transit country or stopover country within 3 days.
>     (4) For e Visa holders, visa must be attached to traveler’s passport and who is traveling from the US, Canada, Australia, New Zealand through South Korea are allowed to enter Korea without a visa.

Note that this program *does not* allow for an overnight landside transit that would permit you to stay in a hotel; people with passports from Nepal are not eligible to transit landside except in a transit tour.

> In addition to existing eligible persons for the no-visa entry for transfer tourists bound for a third country, a foreigner who transfers at Incheon International Airport to their home country or a third country, and those who participates in the Transit Tourism Program (hereinafter referred to as ‘General Transfer Passenger’)
>
> ※However, nationals of 24 countries with visa requirements for Jeju Island are not included. (Ghana, Nigeria, Macedonia, Sudan, Syria, Afghanistan, Iran, Iraq, Cuba, Palestine, Yemen, Gambia, Senegal, Bangladesh, Kyrgyzstan, Pakistan, Somalia, Uzbekistan, Nepal, Cameroon, Sri Lanka, Republic of the Union of Myanmar, Egypt)

To sign up for a transit tour, [book online](https://www.airport.kr/ap/en/trn/trnTourMain.do) or visit the Transit Tour desk in Terminal 1 or Terminal 2.

And as always, entry is at the discretion of the immigration officers; you might be refused entry for the tour even though you appear to qualify.

Answer (score 0):

Nepali passport holders were allowed to go out of ICN with valid US visa but since October 2018 it is not allowed to go out of airport for city tour etc...

Answer (score 0):

Transit tourists bound for another country
Eligibility
Nationals of countries, except for the 24 excluded countries (Syria, Sudan, Iran, Macedonia, Cuba, Kosovo, Palestine, Afghanistan, Iraq, Nigeria, Ghana, Yemen, Gambia, Senegal, Bangladesh, Kyrgyzstan, Pakistan, Somalia, Uzbekistan, Nepal, Cameroon, Sri Lanka, Myanmar, Egypt) that are not granted visa free entry into Korea
Applicable to…
Persons holding a visa (re-entry permit, permanent residency, etc.) to enter the U.S. (including Guam and Saipan), Canada, Australia, or New Zealand (hereinafter referred to as "the four advanced countries") 
1) who transit through Korea to go to one of the four advanced countries.
2) who stay in one of the four advanced countries and take a direct flight from the country to Korea to go to a country of origin or a third country. 
i) A person who has an entry visa for one of 30 European countries, and wishes to travel to 30 European countries through South Korea, or departs from one of 30 European countries, and wishes to travel one’s home country or the third country through South Korea. 
Eligibility 
(1)A person who has a departure ticket to the countries above within 30 days from South Korea, for who has not been an illegal alien and non endorsable offences. 
(2) In the past 3 years, a person who has not been denied entry to Korea, who has not given deportation order from Korea and a person who has not been an illegal alien and a person who has not violated laws. 
(3) A person who stayed in transit country or stopover country within 3 days. 
(4) For e Visa holders, visa must be attached to traveler’s passport and who is traveling from the US, Canada, Australia, New Zealand through South Korea are allowed to enter Korea without a visa.

Comment: This looks like it is copied from a site. If so, can you post a link to the site. If you wrote it yourself, can you please also post a link to an official site that supports your claim.